# Issue with qTip in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, qtip2

I am using the qTip2 plugin and having some issues with Internet Explorer 9.  Works great in Chrome.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/KPusE/).

Can someone explain to me why it does not load in IE?

**HTML**

```
<div id="tooltip">Here is a tooltip</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#tooltip').qtip({
    content: 'little big town',
    hide: {
        fixed: true,
        delay: 200
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include resources directly from github.

> SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/Craga89/qTip2/master/dist/jquery.qtip.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch

Adding it directly to the JavaScript pane works.